# Condition for Quintic Reciprocity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, quintics

Let $p=x^2+11x-1=1\pmod 5$ be a prime. Show that $x$ is a quintic residue $\pmod p$. It holds for $x<200$ and should hold for all such $x$. Any proof ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I imagine you'd want to look at how the 5th cyclotomic polynomial ($(x^5-1)/(x-1)$) might factor. I'm guessing, though.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more general result . . .

Let $x$ be an integer, and let $n=x^2+11x-1$.

**Claim:**$\;$If $n$ is not a multiple of $5$, then $x$ is a $5$-th power, mod $n$.

**Proof:**

Let $a$ be an integer such that $5a\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;n)$, and let $w=a(x+3)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;w^5&=\bigl(a(x+3)\bigr)^5\\[4pt]
&\equiv (3125a^5)x\;(\text{mod}\;n)\;\;\;\text{[by polynomial long division]}\\[4pt]
&\equiv \bigl((5a)^5\bigr)x\;(\text{mod}\;n)\\[4pt]
&\equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;n)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which proves the claim.